# How do I get the view position of a clicked checkedbutton and how to set it checked based on it's position

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I've been stuck for 2 days trying to solve an error
with the displayed checkboxes in my app. I've created an activity that displays list of installed apps with checkboxes on the side of each displayed app. When I click on a checkbox of a specific app e.g Facebook some of other apps' checkboxes get marked without them been clicked. I don't know why this is happening, I'll appreciate it if you help me :D. I've used a list view with array adapter to display the list of installed apps.

ArrayAdapter

```
public class ListofAppsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {

private List<ApplicationInfo> applicationInfoList;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;
private int x = 0;

SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;


public ListofAppsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<ApplicationInfo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.applicationInfoList = objects;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(applicationInfoList.size());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((null != applicationInfoList) ? applicationInfoList.size() : 0);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != applicationInfoList) ? applicationInfoList.get(position) : null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
      public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
       View view = convertView;

      if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
     context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listsofapps_layout, null);
      }

      ApplicationInfo data = applicationInfoList.get(position);

      if (data != null) {
        ImageView app_logo = view.findViewById(R.id.appicon);
        CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.add_app);
        app_logo.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
     //                add_app.setText(appDetailsList.get(position).name);

        checkBox.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
      }


     //
     //        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     //            @Override
     //            public void onClick(View view) {
     //
     //                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked JIMMY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //
     //                if (x == 4 && !add_app.isChecked()) {
     //                    Toast.makeText(context, "You reached your limit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //                    add_app.setChecked(false);
     //                    return;
     //                }
     //
     //                if (!add_app.isChecked()) {
     //                    x++;
     //                    add_app.setChecked(true);
     //                    return;
     //                }
     //
     //                if (add_app.isChecked()) {
     //                    x--;
     //                    add_app.setChecked(false);
     //                    return;
     //                }
     //
     //               }
     //
     //             });

            return view;
         }

     }
```

The Activity

```
public class SelectAppsActivity extends ListActivity {

private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private ListofAppsAdapter listofAppsAdapter = null;

RelativeLayout goBackappsHolder, proceedappsHolder;
ListView listsofappsrecyclerview;

CharSequence packageName, app_Name;
Drawable icon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_apps);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkTheme));
    }


    goBackappsHolder = findViewById(R.id.goBackappsHolder);
    proceedappsHolder = findViewById(R.id.proceedappsHolder);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new loadApps().execute();
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try {

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(SelectAppsActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(SelectAppsActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications) {

    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> appList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

    for (ApplicationInfo info : installedApplications) {

        try {
            if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                appList.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return appList;

}

private class loadApps extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        listofAppsAdapter = new ListofAppsAdapter(SelectAppsActivity.this, R.layout.listsofapps_layout, applist);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        setListAdapter(listofAppsAdapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(unused);
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
   progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SelectAppsActivity.this, null, "Loading app info...");
   super.onPreExecute();
     }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Please show a short reproducible piece of code, otherwise we can only make guesses.

Comment: I've posted the updated. Kindly help if you may.

Comment: Rather than trying to create a click listener for your `View` container, you should instead dynamically add a click listener for the check box itself at the same time as you create the check box, that way it can never select other check boxes by mistake.

Comment: I've tried and the results are still the same.

Comment: In your commented out code, what does `add_app` refer to? You need to reference the correct check box when you use `add_app.setChecked(true);`, because it sounds like you never change the value of `add_app`, so any click events will only ever check that check box.

Comment: Kindly show me how that can be achieved. _You need to reference the correct check box when you use add_app.setChecked(true);, because it sounds like you never change the value of add_app, so any click events will only ever check that check box_

Comment: Simply reference the correct check box, for example `theCorrectCheckBox.setChecked(true);` which will set the correct check box to checked. I am not going to do your work for you, you have not shown enough code in your question to work out what is happening so I do not know how you are creating or managing your check boxes within the ListView and can not provide a simple fix. You would typically have some way to directly reference the correct check box, or you would have a list of check boxes, and use the `int` value of the selected item to get the correct check box from a list and check it.

Comment:  Ok understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now known how to solve it. Override the following methods.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```